# Wiengine Built-in Dialog

Tags: android

I am making a game in android using Wiengine. I can show a native dialog by running it on main UI thread but the problem is the background music gets paused while dialog has focus. 
Can any one let me know about built-in dialog functionality of Wiengine.

Answer (score 0):

Because game activity is paused by dialog activity, so the background music stopped. It goes open source, you can view code to know what wiengine dialog does
https://github.com/stubma/WiEngine